# R gsub add leading line break

Tags: r, gsub

I need to add a leading lines break "\n" to a list of axis label names in R. I cannot work out how to do this with gsub. For example, I need "Q1\n/\n15" to read "\nQ1\n/\n15". Neither google nor the help commands are leading me to the answer. Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @joran: pssh, too easy. `gsub("^(.)","\n\\1","Q1\n/\n15")`. :)

Comment: @Joshua:  "there's an emacs keystroke for that"    ~_*

Comment: Thank you all. @joran, I am indeed an idiot for not thinking of that. And thanks Joshua, I will use that one and learn a bit more about regular expressions.

Comment: While we're at it: `sprintf("\n%s", "Q1\n/\n15")`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich even simpler: `gsub("^","\n","Q1\n/\n15")`.

Comment: @joran why not post an answer?

Comment: @David Cause I got pulled away from the computer.

Answer (score 6):

So there are about 4 answers in the comments (as of this writing), so I'll just summarize them in a proper answer.

```
examp <- "Q1\n/\n15"

paste("\n", examp, sep="")
gsub("^(.)","\n\\1",examp)
sprintf("\n%s", examp)
gsub("^", "\n", examp)
```

all of which give

```
[1] "\nQ1\n/\n15"
```

And all of which are properly vectorized (that is, if `examp <- c("Q1\n/\n15", "Q1\n/\n16")`, all return `[1] "\nQ1\n/\n15" "\nQ1\n/\n16"`.

Comment: Watch out for `gsub("^(.)","\n\\1",examp)`, as it will not work on empty lines (i.e. lines containing only a newline).

For this specific question, it looks like that can never be the case, but this can trip you up if you reuse the code somewhere else.